# Maximum amount of simultaneous xhr requests?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am making a small web app that allows the user to drag a slider to show different content. Each time the slider is moved, the client uses the HTML5 Geolocation to get its position and then sends a XMLHttpRequest to the server for new content.

The problem is if the user moves the slider a bit too many times and too fast, it causes errors.

code:

```
function update(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "request_handler.php";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = xhr.responseText;
            //doing stuff
        }
    }
    // since HTML5 Geolocation is a asynchronous function, and i have to make 
    // sure that i get the users clients position before i send the request, i  
    // pass the sendRequest function below as a callback function to the 
    // Geolocation function
    function sendRequest(latitude,longitude) {

        try{
            xhr.send("latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude);
            console.log("Success")
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log("Error message: %s",err);
        }        

    }
    //This function gets user position and then calls sendRequest if it was
    //Successfull
    Geoposition.updatePosition(sendRequest);
}
//EDIT:
var Geolocation = {
    sendRequestFunction: null,
    options: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    },
    success: function(pos) {
        if (sendRequestFunction) {
        sendRequestFunction(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        };
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    },
    updatePosition: function(callbackFunction) {
        sendRequestFunction = callbackFunction;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Geolocation.success, Geolocation.error, Geolocation.options);
    },
};
```

So as you can see i have a try-catch around the send request function. These are the error messages i get in ff and chrome when i move the Slider to many times fast.

- Firefox: "Error message: [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult:
  "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame ::
  http://localhost/***/myscript.js :: sendRequest :: line 29"  data:
  no]"
- Chrome: "Error message: DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on
  'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED."

I am trying this on a Wampserver2 (it uses an Apache server).

So my question is really: Whats wrong?
I read somewhere that browsers only allow a certain amount of xhr request simultaneously (around 6-7 if a remember correct). Although i can get this error if i drag the slider only 3-4 times rapidly, could this be the porblem anyway? Is there better approaches to this?

EDIT:
Added the updatePosition() function. It is in the namespace that i call Geoposition.

EDIT 2:
If you are here because of the title, this problem had nothing to do with any "maximum amount of simultaneous xhr request" that i suspected.

Comment: Show us your `updatePosition` function. It sounds as if it doesn't call its callback correctly (e.g. multiple times), which means the `send` method is called on an `xhr` object in the wrong state (as chrome says).

Comment: updatePosition added. thanks taking the time.

Comment: Yes, there's your mistake. It will call the same `sendRequestFunction` multiple times if `updatePosition` was invoked in quick succession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart `sendRequestFunction` being an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and not your local `GeoLocation` property, you must not use a free variable in the asynchronous `updatePosition` method. Subsequent calls will overwrite the previous value, and when later your `getCurrentPosition` callbacks are invoked then each of them will call the same `sendRequestFunction`. Which is fatal to your `xhr` object, as it does not like to be sent multiple times (that's just what the error messages say, the request is in a state where `send()` is invalid).

```
var Geolocation = {
    options: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    },
    updatePosition: function(callbackFunction) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            if (typeof callbackFunction == "function") {
                callbackFunction(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            }
        }, Geolocation.error, Geolocation.options);
    }
};
```

Also you may want to consider throttling your geolocalisation and ajax calls.

Comment: wow, you're an angel! thanks, everything works fine. will look into throttling.